# which is more efficient, one method call with a list of values or multiple calls for each value?

Tags: java, list, call

I have a method that reads from values from a file (reading method) and call another method from a Data Access Object (DAO) class which store these values into DB (storing method). My question is: shall i pass all the values read in the reading method as a list to the storing method ( which saves hundreds of method calls, but introduce  the need for creation of the list in the reading method iteration over the list in the storing method), or shall i make a separate call to the storing method for each value ( which means hundreds of method calls, but without the need for list creation and iteration). which approach is more efficient from a performance and good practice view of point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple values, so *someone* has to iterate over the values. The only question is: who?

Generally speaking: As soon as you talk about DB access (reading and writing) the overhead of allocating a list, iterating over it and doing some method calls is negligible to the overhead of *one* DB call (we talk about *hundreds* of call, not *billions*, right?). A DB call is in most cases something like a remote procedure call and writing to a database will write to disk - another great performance sucker.

So in most cases you gain performance if you minimize the calls to the DB. And that can be done more easily if you DB access layer knows the *complete* job. So if you give the DAO a list it can do stuff like prepared statement, batch updates and what not. Given only bits and pieces those things are impossible to do with good performance.

Answer (score 0):

You should read all of them at once, as a `List` and use something like JDBC Batch Update to store them all at once or in batches.

However, doing them all one by one is definitely a no-no. It will make too many network / IO operations.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to be sure is to time the various options. However, since you are hitting a database in this process, that is likely to be dominant. The variant that reduces the database access is liable to be the fastest. If both variants have the same impact on the database then I'd expect them to take similar amounts of time. Calling methods and creating objects are orders of magnitude faster than communicating with your database.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the harddisk is the biggest overhead here. Do the reading from harddisk once, if you can. If not, read into a buffer and refill it after you're done with it. This operation is suitable for Threading, give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Database resources are limited, database hit should be minimized for better performance.

If you compare the cost of database hit and operating on a list, it's negligible.

So create a List and try to do batch operation instead of doing one operation per record.

Less database interaction is always a good practice and is also highly performing option.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question with respect to good practice, you have to consider the usage of the DAO method across your application. If you see it being called multiple times for multiple values from a single point of origin, then I think you should pass a List to the method. But if you have more cases of only one value calls to the method, then you should define it at that granularity.

What others said about DB access still holds. Try to batch multiple DB accesses if that is possible in your case.